# Python ProgressBar2 in notepad++

Tags: python-3.x, package, notepad++

I want to use progressbar2.

My editor is notepad++

When I use progressbar2 in IDLE or cmd interpreter, it work.

But I use it notepad++, it dosen't work.

I think notepad++'s package update is late.

How to solve it??

Comment: This [module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar2)? Really wonder there is any relationship with a python module & a editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`progressbar2` is a package for `python` it seems to be indicating the progress of your application. Notepadd++ is just an IDE where you can edit your code, you still use `python` to actually execute the code. I would suggest looking for some other way to time your app's execution that doesn't depend on your text editor.